# How do I create a dataframe out of two lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists, both have the same numer of elements (48 each). I want to create a dataframe that has one of the lists as the columns, and the other list as the values for said columns. Like the following example:

```
list_1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

```
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want the resulting dataframe to be like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

What am I missing? Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

I've tried using pandas:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=fields)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[83], line 1
----> 1 dataframe_maybe = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=fields)
      3 dataframe_maybe

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:762, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    754         mgr = arrays_to_mgr(
    755             arrays,
    756             columns,
   (...)
    759             typ=manager,
    760         )
    761     else:
--> 762         mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
    763             data,
    764             index,
    765             columns,
    766             dtype=dtype,
    767             copy=copy,
    768             typ=manager,
    769         )
    770 else:
    771     mgr = dict_to_mgr(
    772         {},
...
    418 passed = values.shape
    419 implied = (len(index), len(columns))
--> 420 raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (48, 1), indices imply (48, 48)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `pd.DataFrame([list_2], columns=list_1)`.

Your data needs to be like an `ndarray`